# POCO class not being transformed into proxy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running into a really weird and hair loss causing error. I've been working with EF and the repository pattern for many years, but now I got this really weird error: my `Telephone` POCO class is not being transformed into proxy. Every other POCO class becomes a proxy BUT `Telephone`. I've deleted and recreated that file, the repository file and so on... I can't see what (likely very dumb) error I'm making here. This is how I add it to the context:

```
public virtual T Add()
{
    return DbSet.Add(DbSet.Create());
}

public virtual T Add(T entity)
{
    var temp = Add();
    PropertyCopy.CopyValues(entity, temp);

    return DbSet.Add(temp);
}
```

Where DbSet: `DbContext.Set<T>()`

Here you can see the difference:

### Not working

[image]

[image]

### Working

[image]

[image]

This is the `Telephone` POCO class:

https://gist.github.com/eestein/ce6c453e806b1b1c6ed5ac43410f3687

And this is the `EmployeeProfile` POCO class (this and all the others, become proxy):

https://gist.github.com/eestein/5a657ebe1ead739eaac5b00f2043bebe

This is how they are created:

```
var mobileTelephone = Context.Add(new Telephone
{
    AreaCode = model.ManagerAreaCode.Value,
    CountryCode = model.ManagerCountryCode.Value,
    Number = int.Parse(model.ManagerPhone),
    IsDefault = true,
    Type = TelephoneType.Mobile,
    IsValidated = LoggedUser?.IsSuperAdmin() ?? false
});
var profile = Context.Add(new EmployeeProfile
{
    Rank = EmployeeRank.Administrator
});
```

I appreciate any help, as I'm almost out of hair to pull...

Comment: What problem is this causing? You shouldn't care whether or not the classes are proxies. Why are you running `DbSet.Create()` and then copying the properties? Why not just add the entity you're passing? In my experience, proxy classes are only created (and actually, are only useful), when you are *loading* rows, not creating one in memory.

Comment: @Rob hey man, thanks for the comment. The problem is that I run some pre and post entity's creation methods. And it works for the others, just not this one. It is saved to the DB, but it bypasses my pre and post events since it's not a proxy.

Comment: How are your pre/post methods defined? It seems like a bad idea to rely on proxy creation for business logic. Your `public virtual T Add(T entity)` method seems suspect. Why not just implement it as `return DbSet.Add(entity);` rather than creating a new object and copying the values over?

Comment: @Rob I honestly would have to undo and test that to validate. I created (and have been using) this library about 4-5 years ago. If I recall it correctly it was due to some issue with existing classes, but again I'd have to confirm. As per your first question, I need the entity's state. Whenever in my code `Save()` is called I run my pre and post methods based on their `EntityState`. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob according to Michael's link there's nothing I can do, since EF won't create proxies if the class does not "need" it. I wasn't aware of that. And is pretty weird that I never ran into this issue before. Anyway, I'm going to adapt the code so it can handle that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you *need* Entity Framework to create a proxy in this case? My guess is you don't, because you aren't making use of lazy loading with the telephone class. You have no virtual properties listed. While in the EmployeeProfile class you do.

> Note that the EF will not create proxies for types where there is
>   nothing for the proxy to do. This means that you can also avoid
>   proxies by having types that are sealed and/or have no virtual
>   properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx

Comment: I understand. I wasn't aware of that. I thought the proxy creation was default for all entity classes. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out to me, I think I'll need to adapt my code.